# Adding data to ConnectableObservable

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

How do I put data in a ConnectableObservable? I'm asking this for the case where the data of an observable is not available until an async function completes. A simple example:

```js
function myFunc() {
  let observable = Rx.Observable.create().publish();
  setTimeout(() => console.info('TIMEOUT') || observable.of('data').connect(), 300);
  return observable;
}

myFunc().subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I have also tried

```js
observable.map(() => 'data').connect()
observable.flatMap(() => Observable.of('data')).connect()
```

as an alternative to `.of()` in my example without success.

Answer (score 1):

Observables don't have the `connect()` method. The only exception is the `ConnectableObservable` that is returned for example by the `publish()` operator.

You can do for example the following:

```
let source = Observable.create(observer => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => observer.next('data'), 300);

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };
}).publish();

source.connect();
source.subscribe(console.log);
```

Edit:

```
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(...)
  .publish();

let o1 = observable
  .map(val => true)
  .flatMap(...)
  .subscribe(...);

observable.connect();
```

... or ...

```
let observable = Rx.Observable.create(...);
let o1 = observable
  .map(val => true)
  .flatMap(...)
  .publish();

o1.subscribe(...);
o1.connect();
```

Comment: That's why `observable` is a `ConnectableObservable`. I'm looking for a way to change the observable after it's initial creation similar to `deferred = $q.defer()`, `deferred.resolve('data')`.

Comment: But you're using `observable.map(() => 'data').connect()` which never works because `map()` always returns just `Observable` and not `ConnectableObservable`.

Comment: That's something I didn't know. Can't you `.map()` a `ConnectableObservable` to a `ConnectableObservable`? Also I don't need to use `.map()`. I just want to add data to an `Observable` after it's initial creation in a deferred manner. Similar to `$q`'s `deferred`.

Comment: That's not possible at the moment. However it's been mentioned on RxJS Github, see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2487#issuecomment-288871607.
I updated my answer with two more examples of `publish()`, maybe one of them is closer to what you need.

Comment: Won't `observable` in your first example become a `ConnectableObservable` and lose access to the `.map()` function? I'm lost in your examples since I don't see where you introduce a new data into the Observable.

Comment: `ConnectableObservable` class inherits `Observable` class so it has all the operators as `Observable`. You can send data inside the callbacks to `Observable.create()`. Btw, it's not that hard to try this code yourself and see that it works.